# Login page lets user get inside the app even if the authentication failed

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-authentication

I've made a simple app with phone authentication (sms).
My problem splits to two, the first part is that the verification code (sms) is always wrong somehow (I do get it, however it doesn't pass the confirmation), and the second part (as stated in the title) is that the user can still access the main activities even if authentication failed.

the function is invoked via a button.
the function is :

```
  signIn(){
    const appVerifier = this.recaptchaVerifier;
    const phoneNumberString = "+972" + this.phoneNumber.substring(1,10);
    firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumberString, appVerifier)
    .then( confirmationResult => {
      // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
      // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
      let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Enter the Confirmation code',
      inputs: [{ name: 'confirmationCode', placeholder: 'Confirmation Code' }],
      buttons: [
        { text: 'Cancel',
          handler: data => { console.log('Cancel clicked'); }
        },
        { text: 'Send',
          handler: data => {
            confirmationResult.confirm(data.confirmationCode)
            .then(function (result) {
              // User signed in successfully.
              this.uid = result.user.uid
              this.addUser(this.fullName, this.uid);
              console.log(result.user);
              // ...
              }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Invalid code") // always getting here
              });
            }
          }
        ]
      });
      prompt.present();
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log("SMS not sent")
    });
  }
```

**UPDATE (app.component)**
the decision is made in the constructor of app.component.ts

```
  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    var that = this
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();


      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
          that.rootPage = TabsPage; // even though auth failed, he comes here
        } else {
          that.rootPage = LoginPage;
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: I don't know much about firebase, but with ionic, if you want to prevent users from entering pages you need to use ionviewcanenter: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

Answer (score 0):

I dont see it in your code but anywhere you call a method to push the main App-Page. You only should show the main App-Page after User successfully logged in. If this dont work maybe the user comes inside of your app, because the Firebase function is asynchron.